# Does the root -batic have a source meaning?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, greek

I'm curious about the words aerobatic and acrobatic. They seem of Latin origin and I wonder if anyone could enlighten me as to the meaning of the "-batic" portion of these words.

Edit: I stand corrected, it is of Greek origin.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question, but has more to do with Latin than with English. You may be interested in supporting the Linguistics.SE proposal in Area51.  Also, @Cerberus might be able to answer this question.

Comment: I agree with @Kit, and think this could be interesting. However, if you found out that it's of Greek origin, wouldn't you be able to find the source meaning as well?

Comment: @simchona The Greek word is akrobates, which is akros for "high up" or "topmost," but the ending is not so clear. A Classics scholar would probably know.

Comment: @Kit Interesting. Well, hopefully Linguistics can shed light on it. (The OED gives an etymology for it)

Comment: The Greek word for walking on air is αεροβατέω;  aερο- meaning air, -βατέω (or more correctly πατέω) meaning to walk.  How the 'π' became a 'β' is beyond me. As KitΘδς said, maybe Linguistics.SE could shed more light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally from Greek and answerable by simply using a [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=acrobatic).

> [French acrobate, from Greek akrobat s :
>   akros, high; see acro- + bainein, bat-, to walk; see gw - in Indo-European roots.]